# Selecting/Uploading Image to Userform

Tags: macros, userform

I'm creating a userform that has an image box. It has the capability of browsing for file when the user clicks on the box. Ideally, I want the user to be able to upload a picture without having to navigate to Properties. I tried ImageBox.Picture = LoadPicture(PicPath) to upload the file to the imagebox, but I get a 424 error. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Screenshot_Click()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim PicPath As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
PicPath = .SelectedItems(1)
ImageBox.Picture = LoadPicture(PicPath)
Else: Exit Sub
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit where credit is due: Thanks **ccollins48** on the vbaexpress forums!

Private Sub Screenshot_Click()

```
Dim PictFileName As String
PictFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
PicPath = PictFileName

If Len(Dir(PicPath)) = 0 Then
MsgBox PicPath & "Error"
Else
Me.Screenshot.Picture = LoadPicture(PicPath)
Me.Repaint
End If
End Sub
```

Format picture to 3-fmPictureSizeModeZoom